# Storing JSON as TEXT instead of JSONB in YugabyteDB

Tags: jsonb, yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have a column whose value is JSON `string/json`. What should be the preferred type of column JSONB or TEXT?
Does one or the other impact performance/ column size/ read-write time etc?
The value will always be retrieved as full and passed as a param without any computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this exact case, you can store it as TEXT. This would save a little bit of CPU on INSERT because the string would have to be analyzed as valid JSON and converted to JSONB, which underneath is stored in BINARY format.

For all other cases where you may want to select a subset of the JSON object, or do computations over it, or have secondary indexes, you’ll need to store it as JSONB.